# Accessing visible PDF with Chrome Extension Content Script

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension, pdfium

I'm trying to build a Chrome extension to access the binary of a PDF in the case of a user viewing that PDF in a tab in Chrome. I thought that I would use a Content Script to get around file permission issues, and now I'm trying to figure out how to access the binary of the PDF via PDFium through the DOM. Is this possible? Has anyone found a good solution for this? I don't need to do any rendering, I just need the binary representation of the rendered file.